# MAMP suddenly stopped working

Tags: macos, mamp, osx-yosemite

My MAMP install on my local mac has suddenly stopped working.

By stopped working I mean that I can no longer access any of my sites nor can I load the MAMP WebStart page.  I cannot access PhpMyAdmin either. All attempts to any of the pages result in the following:

> The server at localhost can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

I have had MAMP installed on my machine for almost two years without a single problem.

I upgraded the OS to Yosemite a few days ago.

Now today it was working fine this AM and now at 9AM I can no longer access any of my sites or the start page to diagnose the problem.

The MAMP interface to start/stop servers is accessible and it shows and allows me to start and stop the servers.

What I've tried:

- Changing the port ids
- Upgrading MAMP to the latest version

Nothing I have attempted thus far has worked.

Has anyone ever experienced this and if so how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: MAMP is working fine for me on Yosemite, I'm afraid. Have you recently enabled a proxy service? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643412/dns-lookup-failed-error-with-all-browsers

Comment: @emrys57 thanks for the tip.  That actually helped.  I looked at my host file and it had been completely blown away.  Not sure how or why or what caused that to happen.  Luckily I had just sent a copy of my host file to a coworker last week and used that to restore.  It worked!  Thanks again for the tip - every little bit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my etc/hosts file had been completely wiped clean.

Not sure how or why or what caused the file to be blown away.

Luckily I had a copy to restore from.

After the restore everything is once again functioning properly.

Thanks to @emrys57 for the tip to look here: [DNS Lookup failed - Error with all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643412/dns-lookup-failed-error-with-all-browsers)

Cheers!